# Проблема с сертификацией в Кубернетесе

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, gcp

```
    ---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ui-ingress
  namespace: application
  annotations:
    ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: rapidssl-c
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: cs.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: гш
          servicePort: 3000
  - host: bs.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: ро
          servicePort: 3000
```

Неподтягивает сертификат, который указан сертификат есть. Создан контроллер, который создает лоадбалнсер, ингрес аттачиться на лоад балансер. В днс прописывается адресс лоад балансер. Но сертификат не подтягивается. Что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы nginx-ingress терминировал https в http, нужно настроить секцию tls в ingress, в spec:

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ui-ingress
  namespace: application
  annotations:
    ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: rapidssl-c
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: cs.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: po
          servicePort: 3000
  - host: bs.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: ро
          servicePort: 3000
tls:
- hosts:
  - cs.com
  secretName: cs-com
- hosts:
  - bs.com
  secretName: bs-com
```

А так же нужно добавить секрет

```
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
  tls.crt: BASE_64_ENCODED_CERTIFICATE_OR_CERTIFICATES_BUNDLE_HERE
  tls.key: BASE_64_ENCODED_PRIVATE_KEY_HERE
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: cs-com
type: kubernetes.io/tls
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
  tls.crt: BASE_64_ENCODED_CERTIFICATE_OR_CERTIFICATES_BUNDLE_HERE
  tls.key: BASE_64_ENCODED_PRIVATE_KEY_HERE
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: bs-com
type: kubernetes.io/tls
```